# Script to handle automated installation in Iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want a script to automate installing and uninstalling my application on an iPhone.

Comment: On an unjailbroken phone? Not possible to my knowledge.

Comment: not on a jailbroken one. My requirement is to include the installation and uninstalling procedure also to the automation script.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this on a non-jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this on a normal iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't permit code to execute outside the run environment. Once your app is built, submitted, and approved, Apple will handle the installation of it on the devices via the App Store.